# Wrong line drawing for coords sequence

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Here is a gif showing my problem:

[image: Click here for gif]

In my example: When I click on the radio buttons, lines have to be generated in this order `-> sion -> sarnen -> altdorf -> bellinzona` and form into a trapeze (trapezium) but unfortunately my code switches the coordinates of the second and third position. I've tried it with other cities so maybe it could be something wrong with the `fxml` (which I don't think). It must be the code in class `FXMLDocumentController`. I get in the console this output:

```
Sarnen            
Line[startX=600.0, startY=347.0, endX=803.0, endY=594.0, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=1.0]
Line[startX=803.0, startY=594.0, endX=373.0, endY=585.0, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=1.0]
Line[startX=373.0, startY=585.0, endX=702.0, endY=347.0, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=1.0]
Line[startX=702.0, startY=347.0, endX=600.0, endY=347.0, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=1.0]
Bellinzona   
Sion    
Altdorf
```

This means just that first sarnen has been created then bellinzona then sion and then altdorf.

`FXMLDocumentController`: I personally think the method `starter()` isn't doing that what it should so have there a first look

```
package tsprealone;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
//import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
//import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

/**
 *
 * @author kbwschuler
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    // private Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING); just a message box 
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorPane;
    @FXML
    private ImageView img;

    @FXML
    private ArrayList<Stadt> stadte = new ArrayList<Stadt>();
    @FXML
    private ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
    @FXML
    private Button generiere;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton zug;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton zurich;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton schaffhausen;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton stgallen;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton aarau;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton chur;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton glarus;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton frauenfeld;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton schwyz;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton luzern;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton sarnen;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton bellinzona;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton sion;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton liestal;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton bern;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton delemont;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton solothurn;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton fribourg;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton neuchatel;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton lausanne;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton genf;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton altdorf;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton stans;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton basel;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton appenzell;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton herisau;

    private ArrayList<Stadt> ausgewaehlt = new ArrayList<Stadt>(); //check if is checked

    @FXML
    private void clearPane(ActionEvent event)
    {
        //anchorPane.getChildren().clear();
        anchorPane.getChildren().removeAll(lines);
        lines.clear();
        anchorPane.getChildren().removeAll(ausgewaehlt);
        ausgewaehlt.clear();

        RadioButton[] allRadioButtons = new RadioButton[] {
                zug, zurich, schaffhausen, stgallen, aarau, chur, glarus, frauenfeld, schwyz, luzern, sarnen, bellinzona, sion, liestal, bern, delemont, solothurn, fribourg, neuchatel, lausanne, genf, altdorf, stans, basel, appenzell, herisau
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < allRadioButtons.length; i++) {
            RadioButton setToUnSelected = allRadioButtons[i];
            for (Stadt stadtToUnSelected : stadte) {
                stadtToUnSelected.setIsClicked(false);
            }
            setToUnSelected.setSelected(false);
        }


    }
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        addCities();

        for (Stadt stadt : stadte) {
            if (stadt.isIsClicked()) {
                ausgewaehlt.add(stadt);
                if(ausgewaehlt.size() == 1)
                {

                    /*alert.setTitle("Warnung");
                    alert.setHeaderText("Schau, eine Warnung wurde herausgegeben!");
                    alert.setContentText("Du hast nur eine Stadt ausgewÃ¤hlt. Um das Programm korrekt laufen zu lassen, muss man mehr als eine Stadt auswÃ¤hlen.");

                    alert.showAndWait();
                    System.err.println("Nur eine Stadt ausgewÃ¤hlt");*/
                    //alles kommentiere adel
                }
            }
        }

        starter();
        for (Stadt stadt : ausgewaehlt) {
            System.out.println(stadt.getName());

            for(Line line: lines)
            {

                    try {
                        anchorPane.getChildren().add(line);
                        do {
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }
                        while(ausgewaehlt.size() < lines.size());

                    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
                    {


                    }

            }

        }
    }


    public void addCities(){

        stadte.add(new Stadt("Zug", zug.getLayoutX(), zug.getLayoutY(), check(zug)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Zurich", zurich.getLayoutX(), zurich.getLayoutY(), check(zurich)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Schaffhausen", schaffhausen.getLayoutX(), schaffhausen.getLayoutY(), check(schaffhausen)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Aarau", aarau.getLayoutX(), aarau.getLayoutY(), check(aarau)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Chur", chur.getLayoutX(), chur.getLayoutY(), check(chur)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Glarus", glarus.getLayoutX(), glarus.getLayoutY(), check(glarus)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Frauenfeld", frauenfeld.getLayoutX(), frauenfeld.getLayoutY(), check(frauenfeld)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Schwyz", schwyz.getLayoutX(), schwyz.getLayoutY(), check(schwyz)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Luzern", luzern.getLayoutX(), luzern.getLayoutY(), check(luzern)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Sarnen", sarnen.getLayoutX(), sarnen.getLayoutY(), check(sarnen)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Bellinzona", bellinzona.getLayoutX(), bellinzona.getLayoutY(), check(bellinzona)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Sion", sion.getLayoutX(), sion.getLayoutY(), check(sion)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Liestal", liestal.getLayoutX(), liestal.getLayoutY(), check(liestal)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Bern", bern.getLayoutX(), bern.getLayoutY(), check(bern)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Delemont", delemont.getLayoutX(), delemont.getLayoutY(), check(delemont)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Solothurn", solothurn.getLayoutX(), solothurn.getLayoutY(), check(solothurn)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Fribourg", fribourg.getLayoutX(), fribourg.getLayoutY(), check(fribourg)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Neuchatel", neuchatel.getLayoutX(), neuchatel.getLayoutY(), check(neuchatel)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Lausanne", lausanne.getLayoutX(), lausanne.getLayoutY(), check(lausanne)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Genf", genf.getLayoutX(), genf.getLayoutY(), check(genf)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Altdorf", altdorf.getLayoutX(), altdorf.getLayoutY(), check(altdorf)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Stans", stans.getLayoutX(), stans.getLayoutY(), check(stans)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Basel", basel.getLayoutX(), basel.getLayoutY(), check(basel)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Appenzell", appenzell.getLayoutX(), appenzell.getLayoutY(), check(appenzell)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("Herisau", herisau.getLayoutX(), herisau.getLayoutY(), check(herisau)));
        stadte.add(new Stadt("St Gallen", stgallen.getLayoutX(), stgallen.getLayoutY(), check(stgallen)));

    }

    public void starter() {

        for(int i = 0; i<ausgewaehlt.size(); i++)
        {
                if(i != ausgewaehlt.size() - 1){ 

                    lines.add(new Line(ausgewaehlt.get(i).getxCoord() + 9, ausgewaehlt.get(i).getyCoord() + 9, ausgewaehlt.get(i+1).getxCoord() + 9, ausgewaehlt.get(i+1).getyCoord() + 9));
                }else {
                    lines.add(new Line(ausgewaehlt.get(i).getxCoord() + 9, ausgewaehlt.get(i).getyCoord() + 9, ausgewaehlt.get(0).getxCoord() + 9, ausgewaehlt.get(0).getyCoord() + 9));
                }

        }



    }

    public boolean check(RadioButton rb) {
        if (rb.isSelected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        //addCities();
        //starter();
    }

}
```

FXMLDocument.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" prefHeight="773.0" prefWidth="1184.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="tsprealone.FXMLDocumentController">
  <children>

    <ImageView fx:id="img" fitHeight="771.0" fitWidth="1184.0">
      <image>
        <Image url="@schweizerkarte-schweiz.png" />
      </image>
    </ImageView>
    <RadioButton fx:id="zug" layoutX="659.0" layoutY="228.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="zurich" layoutX="659.0" layoutY="166.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="stgallen" layoutX="873.0" layoutY="145.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="schaffhausen" layoutX="682.0" layoutY="51.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="aarau" layoutX="538.0" layoutY="159.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="chur" layoutX="909.0" layoutY="344.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="glarus" layoutX="794.0" layoutY="275.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="frauenfeld" layoutX="746.0" layoutY="94.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="schwyz" layoutX="694.0" layoutY="293.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="luzern" layoutX="599.0" layoutY="275.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="bellinzona" layoutX="794.0" layoutY="585.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="sion" layoutX="364.0" layoutY="576.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="liestal" layoutX="462.0" layoutY="121.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="bern" layoutX="382.0" layoutY="315.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="delemont" layoutX="367.0" layoutY="168.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="solothurn" layoutX="408.0" layoutY="225.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="fribourg" layoutX="319.0" layoutY="367.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="neuchatel" layoutX="258.0" layoutY="302.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="lausanne" layoutX="180.0" layoutY="474.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="genf" layoutX="53.0" layoutY="576.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="stans" layoutX="622.0" layoutY="306.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="basel" layoutX="423.0" layoutY="94.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="appenzell" layoutX="882.0" layoutY="169.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="herisau" layoutX="849.0" layoutY="154.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <Button fx:id="generiere" layoutX="1035.0" layoutY="640.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Generiere Linien" />
     <Button fx:id="clear" layoutX="1035.0" layoutY="690.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clearPane" text="LÃ¶sche Linien" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="sarnen" layoutX="591.0" layoutY="338.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="altdorf" layoutX="693.0" layoutY="338.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: I couldn't read everything, can you display the polygon's generation code? is it the `starter` method ?

Comment: @BoHalim i think its the starter() method .. just lines being added into arraylist

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Stadt stadt : stadte) {
    if (stadt.isIsClicked()) {
        ausgewaehlt.add(stadt);
        if(ausgewaehlt.size() == 1)
        {

            /*alert.setTitle("Warnung");
            alert.setHeaderText("Schau, eine Warnung wurde herausgegeben!");
            alert.setContentText("Du hast nur eine Stadt ausgewÃ¤hlt. Um das Programm korrekt laufen zu lassen, muss man mehr als eine Stadt auswÃ¤hlen.");

            alert.showAndWait();
            System.err.println("Nur eine Stadt ausgewÃ¤hlt");*/
            //alles kommentiere adel
        }
    }
}
```

This adds the cities in the same order in which they occur in the `stadte` list. This may or may not be the same order the user clicked the buttons...

In this case it is not...

The better idea would be adding a `RadioButton` to the list when it's selected. I recommmend adding the `Stadt` instances as to the `RadioButton`s instead of adding them to a list. Also remove the `clicked` property (or how you call it) from the class, since this doesn't seem necessary.

```
private static void createStadt(RadioButton button, String name) {
    button.setUserData(new Stadt(name, button.getLayoutX(), button.getLayoutY()));
}

private final List<Stadt> selectedCities = new ArrayList<>();

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    createStadt(zug, "Zug");
    createStadt(zurich, "Zurich");
    ...

    allRadioButtons = new RadioButton[] {
            zug, zurich, schaffhausen, stgallen, aarau, chur, glarus, frauenfeld, schwyz, luzern, sarnen, bellinzona, sion, liestal, bern, delemont, solothurn, fribourg, neuchatel, lausanne, genf, altdorf, stans, basel, appenzell, herisau
    };
}

@FXML
private void citySelectionAction(ActionEvent event) {
    RadioButton source = (RadioButton) event.getSource();
    Stadt city = (Stadt) source.getUserData();

    if (source.isSelected()) {
        selectedCities.add(city);
    } else {
        selectedCities.remove(city);
    }
}

private RadioButton[] allRadioButtons;

@FXML
private void clearPane(ActionEvent event) {
    anchorPane.getChildren().removeAll(lines);
    lines.clear();
    selectedCities.clear();

    for (RadioButton button : allRadioButtons) {
        button.setSelected(false);
    }
}

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    final int size = selectedCities.size();
    switch (size) {
        case 1:
            /*alert.setTitle("Warnung");
            alert.setHeaderText("Schau, eine Warnung wurde herausgegeben!");
            alert.setContentText("Du hast nur eine Stadt ausgewÃ¤hlt. Um das Programm korrekt laufen zu lassen, muss man mehr als eine Stadt auswÃ¤hlen.");

            alert.showAndWait();
            System.err.println("Nur eine Stadt ausgewÃ¤hlt");*/
        case 0:
        break;
        default:
            Stadt c1 = selectedCities.get(0);
            Stadt c2 = selectedCities.get(size-1);
            lines.add(new Line(c1.getxCoord() + 9, c1.getyCoord() + 9, c2.getxCoord() + 9, c2.getyCoord() + 9));
            // intentional fallthrough
        case 2:
            Stadt currentCity = selectedCities.get(0);
            for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
                 Stadt nextCity = selectedCities.get(i);
                 lines.add(new Line(currentCity.getxCoord() + 9, currentCity.getyCoord() + 9, nextCity.getxCoord() + 9, nextCity.getyCoord() + 9));
                 currentCity  = nextCity;
            }

    }

    selectedCities.clear();

    // start adding lines starting at the end until a line is found that is
    // already added to the anchorPane
    Line line;
    for (int i = lines.size()-1; (i >= 0) && ((line = lines.get(i)).getParent() == null); i--) {
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(line);
    }

}
```

```xml
...
<RadioButton fx:id="zug" onAction="#citySelectionAction" layoutX="659.0" layoutY="228.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
<RadioButton fx:id="zurich" onAction="#citySelectionAction" layoutX="659.0" layoutY="166.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-color: red;" />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your second and third marked points are third and forth in your ArrayList.

It seems so because in this loop

```
for (Stadt stadt : stadte) {
        if (stadt.isIsClicked()) {
            ausgewaehlt.add(stadt); 
}
```

cities are ordered by their order in FXMLDocument.

I advice you to add your cities in list when you are clicking on the city points. When you end marking and click on your "Generiere Linien" button, you just should render the linked lines.